# C program - Left truncatable prime numbers

Tags: c, expression, primes, integer-arithmetic, function-definition

I wrote a c program to check whether a number is left truncatable prime or not. But it doesn't work.
num_digit is used to count the digits, prime_check is to check whether a number is prime or not. I dont know much about C, i am beginner.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
// to check left truncated prime numbers
int main()
{
    int num,flag=0;
    printf("enter a number\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    while (num>0)
    {
        if (prime_check(num)==1) // 1 = true
            {
                int y=num_digit(num);
                num = num-((num/pow(10,(y-1)))*pow(10,(y-1)));
            }
        else
            {
                flag=1;
                break;
            }
    }
    if (flag==0) printf("Congrats, its a left truncated prime number");
    else printf("nope no never\n");

}
int prime_check(int n)
{
    int i,flag=0;
    if (n<=1) return 0;
    else if (n<=3) return 1;
    else
    {
        for (i=2;i<=sqrt(n);i++)
        {
            if(n%i==0)
            {
                flag=1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(flag==0) return 1;
    else return 0;
}
int num_digit(int n)
{
    int i,x=0;
    for (i=1;n!=0;i++)
    {
        n=n/10;
        x++;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Can anyone suggest me which step is wrong? all it does is to check if the number is prime or not.

Comment: `pow(10, 3)` may return something like `999.99999999675321`. Maybe round it up or, better (??), write your own *integer* power function

Comment: @Aman Kumar Where is the variable x used in the statement x=1; declared?

Comment: `for (i=2;i<=sqrt(n);i++)` may have FP truncation issues.; Suggest `for (i=3;i<=n/i;i+=2)`

Comment: @VladfromMoscow my bad, its not x, its actually "flag". btw, it still doesnt work.

Comment: @pmg can you suggest a way to write power function

Comment: Note: `num_digit(0)` returns 0.  Post your troublesome inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: @Aman "can you suggest a way to write power function" --> Try coding  it - it is a good simple exercise.

Comment: @Aman Kumar Is 137 a left truncated prime number?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Would be easier (and faster) to stop using `scanf()` - e.g. if the input was a string, you could just skip the first digit when converting the rest into an integer.

Comment: @Brendan ... or use `scanf("%d%n", &num, &power_of_ten);`

Answer (score 0):

You should not use floating point expressions. They can produce an unexpected result.

For example, let's assume that `num` is equal to `13`.

In this case the expression

```
num/pow(10,(y-1))
```

will yield a double value `1.3` because the return type of the function `pow`  is double. So the whole expression also will have the type double. The code does not use integer arithmetic.

Now the expression

```
((num/pow(10,(y-1)))*pow(10,(y-1)))
```

will yield the double value equal to `13` ( 1.3 * 10 == 13)

As a result the variable `num` after this statement

```
num = num-((num/pow(10,(y-1)))*pow(10,(y-1)));
```

will be equal to `0` instead of the expected value `3`.

Without using floating point functions the program for example can look the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int is_prime( unsigned long long n )
{
    int prime = n % 2 == 0 ? n == 2 : n != 1;
    
    for ( unsigned long long i = 3; prime && i <= n / i; i += 2 )
    {
        prime = n % i != 0;
    }
    
    return prime;
}

size_t number_size( unsigned long long int n )
{
    const unsigned long long Base = 10;
    
    size_t size = 0;
    
    do
    {
        ++size;
    } while ( n /= Base );
    
    return size;
}

int main( void ) 
{
    const unsigned int Base = 10;
    
    unsigned n = 0;
    
    printf( "Enter a non-negative number: " );
    scanf( "%u", &n );
    
    size_t size = number_size( n );
    
    unsigned int power = 1;
    
    while ( --size ) power *= Base;
    
    for ( unsigned int tmp = n; power && is_prime( tmp ); power /= Base )
    {
        tmp %= power;
    }
    
    if ( power == 0 )
    {
        printf( "Congrats, %u is a left truncated prime number.\n", n );
    } 
    else
    {
        printf( "nope no never.\n" );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

For example, the numbers `17`, `13` are left truncatable prime numbers while the numbers `19`, `11` are not left truncatable prime numbers.